# Is it possible to rescan ttyACM ports?

Tags: tty, oracle-linux

I have two HP MSAs plugged into my Linux box, running OL-6.5. One in `/dev/ttyACM0` and one in `/dev/ttyACM1`.

Occasionally, I need to restart these MSAs, but when I do restart it will sometimes get reassigned to `/dev/ttyACM2` or 3. So far, the only way I have found of resetting them back to 0 and 1 is to restart the machine. But that takes over 5 minutes and I'm sure there must be a quicker way.

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Use custom `udev` rules to give them your own (fixed) symlinks, like `/dev/ttyHP0` and `/dev/ttyHP1`.

Comment: My Arduino device can be found on `/dev/ttyACM0` or `/dev/ttyACM1` and so on. But there is a unique device file in `/dev/serial/by-id`. I'm pretty sure your MSA devices will get some unique device file, too.